# "Access is denied" error during "New-Item" call in PS

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a folder on a server using powershell. The script looks like this:

```
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "myPW" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("myUser", $pass)
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "localhost" -Credential $cred
Invoke-Command -session $session -ScriptBlock {
        New-Item -Path "\\myServer\myShare\" -Name "myFolder" -ItemType directory -Force
    }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Access is denied
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\myServer\myShare:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost 

Access to the path 'myShare' is denied.
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\myServer\myShare:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost

Access to the path 'myFolder' is denied.
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\myServer\myShare\myFolder:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

At first I thought the message is pretty clear an the user I used is missing rights. But here is the thing: If I go to the share in the Explorer and log in with the same user, I can create a folder without any problems. Besides that, the user is Domain Admin.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you're facing a "double hop" problem, read this, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002717/error-when-accessing-unc-paths-through-powershell-script-when-remoting)

Comment: I wonder if this might be the double hop issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a double hop, you're connecting to a PSSession and then trying to access the folder.

As a security measure PowerShell does not allow you to remote to one computer, then remote to another computer from there (even if two of those are the same computer). The exact reasoning is complex and heavily involved in how credentials are used in sessions and I don't fully understand it myself so I won't try to explain but basically it's to prevent the credentials being stolen.

You can do some reading on it [(this looks like a good resource)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee309365(v=vs.85).aspx) but it would be a LOT simpler to just try to work out another way of doing it. You're only remoting to the local computer so you could for example start another PS process.

Comment: Sounds like this could be it. I will look into other ways to call it with other credentials and see if it works.

Comment: You might get away with a .NET copy class if any of them support credentials but I've previously been through this problem extensively and never found anything tidy. Do let me know if you have any luck =)

Comment: I can use `Start-Job` with the `-Credential` parameter. It works fine now. Thank a lot! :-)

Comment: Ooooh because a job doesn't run in a new session. Not applicable for my circumstances but good you found a simple answer =)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using a PSSession for the alternative credentials to access the share, then using `New-PSDrive` might be an alternative way to do it:

```
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "myPW" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("myUser", $pass)

New-PSDrive -Name myShare -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\myServer\myShare\" -Credential $cred
New-Item -Path "myShare:\" -Name "myFolder" -ItemType directory -Force
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but there are acctually more commands in the script block I need the credentials for. This was just the relevant parts for my problem.